# Cannot find message resources under key org.apache.struts.action.MESSAGE in struts

Tags: struts, struts-1

I am getting the following error in the browser window :

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find message resources under key org.apache.struts.action.MESSAGE

I have included the resource file in the struts-config.xml using

And my resource file is stored as WEB-INF/classes/Application.properties file.

Comment: I just got this error and it turns out I had an error in my struts config xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is an old post, but my answer can help, I guess...
I personally wasted some time to make work a poject that had been developped under Tomcat 5.5 under Tomcat 7.

Note : You should name your ressource file : "ApplicationResources"...

There is several reasons why it wouldn't work, but the most common answer I found on the net was : put the line

```
<message-resources parameter="ApplicationResources" null="false" />
```

in your "struts-config.xml".

In my case, this line was already present, and this was the contrary : I had to remove it and replace at the "web.xml" file level by :

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>ApplicationResources</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

in the "servlet" tag.

I'm sorry that I don't have a valuable explanation for this, but my application behaves just fine now.
Does anyone has (an explanation) ?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I was converting my project to maven and my `resources` directory was not correct.

I had struts-config.xml like this:

```
<message-resources parameter="messages.appResources" null="false"/>
```

My pom.xml was like this:

```
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
```

But my `messages` folder was in my project root.  So I moved it to:

```
${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/messages
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sur that you are using the same version of the DTD in the header of struts-config.xml:

I had this error when using two differents versions:

//EN" 
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

and the Pb was solved once the correction made:

Answer (score 0):

An XML might be missing...
In which context is your application running ? Tomcat ? JBoss ?

Try including xalan and xerces dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The following solved my problem:

In Struts Config, include:

(At the top)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC 
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" 
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
```

```
<message-resources
    parameter="common.properties.Common" /> (or the path to your resources file)
```

This error seems to be caused by a lack of a path to message-resource in struts-config.xml
and the DOCTYPE definition at the top of the same.

Answer (score 0):

you should put this line in your struts-config.xml

> < message-resources parameter="ApplicationResources" null="false" **key="ApplicationResources"**  />

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was fixed after delete all unnecessary attributes from `message-resources` element in `struts-config.xml` file. Just like following:

```
<message-resources parameter="ApplicationResources"/>
```